# Raspberry Pi with ESC and PS3 Controller

Tags: pwm, servo

I am new to coding and I am trying to control ESCs through a PS3 controller which will be coded on the Raspberry Pi B+. I think this can be done, but i have read in a lot of places that I need to use an additional board? Is this the case?

I have found some code which i was going to manipulate..

http://www.raspians.com/Knowledgebase/ps3-dualshock-controller-inst...

http://mechnable.com/content/raspberry-pi-controlling-4-servos-via-...

Please advise me on if I need another board? My project: is to create a system which can VTOL. So I wanted to control the ESCs with an input from the PS3 controller.

Comment: "Please advise me on if I need another board?" I have no idea.  What do you want this board to do?

Comment: I have just read online that I might need an arduino board to control the motor. I checked out: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-lesson-9-controlling-a-dc-motor/software

and it states that I need to get a L293D. So I am just a little confused.

Comment: You do not need a L293D to control a servo (you don't need the Adafruit PWM driver board either).  You need a L293D to control an ordinary DC motor.  Are you using any ordinary motors?

Comment: I am using normal motor which is connected to an ESC (I have just taken the motor and esc from a helicopter kit). I have the RPi B+ and i think I should be able to use the GPIOs on that to set up a speed control of the motor?

Comment: If the normal motor is powered/controlled by the ESC you don't need another board.  ESCs are normally controlled using PWM.  The Pi can provide suitable PWM pulses from its gpios.